# Doubts on mass-energy relation

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, mass, mass-energy

Einstein gave this mass-energy relation [$E=mc^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence).
But, using simple mathematical transposing, we get $E$ divided by $m$ equals $c^2$, which gives kinetic energy by mass equals a constant $9×10^{16}$. Is this constant true everytime? If it is not true, how is the mass- energy relation widely accepted?

Comment: In that equation, $E$ is not kinetic energy, but rather rest mass energy. In the answer by GRocks, and usually in relativity, $E$ means the total energy, i.e. kinetic energy plus rest mass energy. The the equation must be amended as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The correct equation is $E=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}m_0c^2$, or, if you like ($\vec{p}$ is the three-momentum)- $$E^2=|\vec{p}|^2c^2+m_0^2c^4$$.

This shows you how the velocity(momentum) of the object comes into the picture when calculating energy. More the $p$, more the $E$, as you'd intuitively expect. The kinetic  energy is $$K.E=E-m_0c^2$$ and clearly $K.E/m$ is not a universal constant, since the numerator has a $p$ dependence.

Note that $m_0$ here is the proper, invariant mass that measures the matter content(or, the energy in the rest frame). In earlier days, people defined things like relativistic mass $\gamma m$ and things like that. This explains the notation $E=mc^2$; it's a different kind of mass from the one I used in my equation. The latter is standard practice now.

Answer (score 1):

The mass energy relation states that mass and energy are equivalent and interconvertible. The law which governs the conversion of mass into energy is $E=mc^2$ as you stated.

But it seems that you have misunderstood the context of this equation. Think it in this way. The energy $E$ is the maximum possible energy the mass can give due to mass energy interconversion and when the whole mass gets converted to energy (which almost never happens, even in nuclear reactions, its always a fraction of the mass which gets converted to energy). However, this does not mean that the mass will surely give the energy out. That $E$, just signifies that if you ever converted the whole mass into energy (which is practically impossible), then you would get a $mc^2$ amount of energy. But as we know from experience, we don't see objects losing all their mass and getting converted to energy spontaneously, and that is why you don't see all the objects with kinetic energy of the order of $9×10^{16} \text{ J}$.